# Проблема при написании shellcode

Tags: c, безопасность, ассемблер, c++

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться (выполняю учебное задание).
Для начала хочу написать шеллкод, который бы запускал командную строку в Windows.
Для этого пишу сначала ассемблер:

```
    push 20646D63h
    mov eax, esp
    push 1
    push eax
    mov eax, 753D27ECh
    call eax
```

Он запускается и работает. (Значит адреса были вычислены верно, как я понимаю.)
Теперь открываю и беру опткодовую реализацию этого ассемблера:

```
        push 20646D63h
00401009 68 63 6D 64 20       push        20646D63h  
        mov eax, esp
0040100E 8B C4                mov         eax,esp  
        push 1
00401010 6A 01                push        1  
        push eax
00401012 50                   push        eax  
        mov eax, 753D27ECh
00401013 B8 EC 27 3D 75       mov         eax,753D27ECh  
        call eax
00401018 FF D0                call        eax
```

То есть, собрав байты вместе, получаю код:

```
"\x68\x63\x6D\x64\x20"
"\x8B\xC4"
"\x6A\x01"
"\x50"
"\xB8\xEC\x27\x3D\x75"
"\xFF\xD0"
```

Нашла на одном из сайтов  способ протестировать работоспособность шеллкода, пытаюсь сделать это:

```
char shellcode[] = "\x68\x63\x6d\x64\x20\x8b\xc4\x6a\x01\x50\xb8\xec\x27\x3d\x75\xff\xd0";
    _asm
    {
        lea eax, shellcode
        jmp eax
    }
```

Однако программа вылетает по ошибке. Сообщение об ошибке похоже на переполнение буфера.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, почему мой шеллкод не работает?

Comment: @777Julia777: А почему бы вам не пройти код под отладчиком? Сразу всё станет самоочевидно.

Comment: @VladD, простите, не до конца понимаю. Ассемблерный код проходить не понимаю зачем, ибо он работает. А как возможно пройти шеллкод отладчиком?

Comment: @777Julia777: Ассемблерный код — это такая штука, что никогда не знаешь, работает он или нет. То есть в одних условиях он может работать, а в других нет.

Например, в некоторых ОС есть защита данных от выполнения, «просто» сделать `jmp` в область данных у вас может и не получиться.

Так что да, стоит пройти ваш код под отладчиком и посмотреть, какая же инструкция вылетает.

Comment: @777Julia777: Ну ёлки-палки.

Код `push 100000h; ret;` в одних условиях выполнится, а в других нет, в зависимости от того, что у вас расположено по адресу `100000h`. Поэтому аргумент «у меня в том примере всё работает» не катит.

Запускайте отладчик, не ленитесь.

Comment: Я могу понять разобрать только то, что ему не нравится инструкция push        20646D63h
Но почему она ему не нравится и как мне ее изменить, я не знаю. Тем более в примере, откуда я это брала, у человека все компилировалось и такой ошибки не возникало...

Comment: @777Julia777: О, уже лучше. Например, у вас может быть проблема со стеком: он не настроен и указывает на «левую» память. Или проблема возникает при _компиляции_?

Comment: @777Julia777: Отлично. Тогда посмотрите, чему равны стековые регистры (`SS:ESP`) в этот момент? (Кстати, у вас код бежит в каком режиме? Не в real mode случайно?)

---
(У вас лимит комментариев, удаляйте старые.)

Comment: @VladD, разобралась, дело было в банальной настройке компилятора...) Спасибо!

Comment: @777Julia777: Отлично! Вот и разобрались. А что была за настройка? (Может быть, стоит опубликовать как ответ на случай, если у кого-то возникнет та же проблема.)

Comment: В линковщике DEP отключила)

Comment: @777Julia777: А, data execution protection! Неудивительно :)